# How to disable Mapbox click event while using measure function?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

So I have read about turning off event listeners with Mapbox. Now I have the current code to create a marker on click.

```
const onClickEventMarker = (event) => {
  setClassName(style.radial);
  props.marker.setPopup(
    new Popup({
      closeOnMove: true,
      anchor: 'center',
      className: style.container,
    })
      .addTo(map)
      .setDOMContent(popupRef.current)
      .setLngLat(event.lngLat.wrap())
  );
  props.marker.setLngLat(event.lngLat.wrap()).addTo(map);
} 
map.on('click', onClickEventMarker);
```

This works fine and it adds a marker to the map as expected.

In mapbox you have the draw functionality.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/measure/

This will, whenever you clicked the map, draw a line on the map to measure a distance for example.

Now I have set a boolean to check whenever measuring is going on and I want the onClickEventMarker to turn off during this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(props.isMeasuring) {
    map.off('click', onClickEventMarker);
  } else {
    map.on('click', onClickEventMarker);
  }
}, [props.isMeasuring]);
```

The expected result would be that the click event turns off, but it doesn't. I have already checked if the code actually goes into the off and on and it does, so that isn't the issue.

Does anyone know a solution to this or am I doing something wrong? I checked alot of posts but can't seem to find a solution. Appreciate the help!